# How do I use Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteFileAsync in Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I'm trying to write a text file to the roaming folder in my Windows 8.1 app. However, all the tutorials I've been able to find were written for Windows 8 and use the Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteFileAsync method which is no longer available in Windows 8.1 apparently. What is the equivalent method for this in 8.1?

Here's the code I have so far, I just don't know what do afterwards to write the file because of the apparent change in APIs:

```
var applicationData = ApplicationData.Current;
var roamingFolder = applicationData.RoamingFolder;

await roamingFolder.CreateFileAsync("file.txt", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

Comment: _"...no longer available in Windows 8.1"_?

Comment: Windows.Storage.FileIO does not exist when I try to use it in the latest Windows 8.1 SDK. I am unable to use it to save a file locally and I do not know of any other way to save a simple text file locally in a Windows 8.1 app. This method used to work in a Windows 8 app but no longer works after the latest Windows 8.1 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. When I used that method in Windows 8, I would type in the full Windows.Storage.FileIO line, but now in Windows 8.1, I only need to type in File.IO.WriteTextAsync() and it'll work. The Windows.Storage part is no longer needed in Windows 8.1 it seems.

Comment: Have a look at `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx`. It explains namespaces. I think your problem lied there.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of `Windows.Storage.File.IO.WriteFileAsync`. You're probably looking for [`Windows.Storage.FileIO` which has `WriteBytesAsync`, `WriteTextAsync`, etc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.fileio.aspx).

Comment: Yeah I believe that's the one, just a typo in the question on my part. I still can't use that API though in a Windows 8.1 app. Windows.Storage doesn't even work.

Comment: Are you sure it's Windows 8.1 and not, e.g., Windows Phone App 8.1 or Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, this app is using the latest Windows 8.1 SDK.

Comment: @Generalkidd Please provide a link to this SDK you keep referring to.